# Difference between `tf.reshape(a, [m, n])` and `tf.transpose(tf.reshape(a, [n, m]))`?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, tensorflow, deep-learning

Actually, I'm doing the homework "Art Generation with Neural Style Transfer" of deeplearning.ai on coursera. In the function `compute_layer_style_cost(a_S, a_G):`

```
a_S = tf.reshape(a_S, [n_H*n_W, n_C])
a_G = tf.reshape(a_G, [n_H*n_W, n_C])

GS = gram_matrix(tf.transpose(a_S))
GG = gram_matrix(tf.transpose(a_G))
```

Why does this code give the right answer, however, the following doesn't:

```
a_S = tf.reshape(a_S, [n_C, n_H*n_W])
a_G = tf.reshape(a_G, [n_C, n_H*n_W])

GS = gram_matrix(a_S)
GG = gram_matrix(a_G)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trivial example that shows the difference between these two expressions:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.range(0, 6)
a = tf.reshape(x, [3, 2])
b = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(x, [2, 3]))

print(x.eval())
print(a.eval())
print(b.eval())
```

The result:

```py
[0 1 2 3 4 5]

[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]

[[0 3]
 [1 4]
 [2 5]]
```

As you can notice, `a` and `b` are different, though have the same shape. That's because the first reshaping "splits" `x` into `[0 1]`, `[2 3]` and `[4 5]`, while the second reshaping into `[0 1 2]` and `[3 4 5]`.